# relationship between PX_SERVERS_EXECUTIONS and USERS OPENING

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I see a single sql with 5 distinct SIDs. Now taking the SQL_ID in V$SQL i find that and the USERS_OPENING=5 but the PX_SERVERS_EXECUTION=1. Also for one sql I see UO=1 but PXSE=2. Can any you pls help me in understanding the relationship of SQL_ID, SID, PX_SERVERS_EXECUTION and USERS_OPENING with each other. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Every column in the data dictionary is described in the *Database Reference*.  Each view has its own page, and below are the definitions from the [`V$SQL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/V-SQL.html#GUID-2B9340D7-4AA8-4894-94C0-D5990F67BE75) page:

- SQL_ID - SQL identifier of the parent cursor in the library cache
- USERS_OPENING - Number of users that have any of the child cursors open
- PX_SERVERS_EXECUTIONS - Total number of executions performed by parallel execution servers (0 when the statement has never been executed in parallel)

To rephrase the definitions and add some details:

- `SQL_ID` is a hash of the text of the SQL statement.
- `USERS_OPENING` is the current number of sessions that have ran the statement (but are not necessarily running it right now).
- `PX_SERVERS_EXECUTIONS` is the total number of parallel servers ever created to process the statement.  For example, every time a statement like `SELECT /*+ PARALLEL(8) */ ...` is executed, the count will increment by probably either 8 or 16.  (And it's odd that you have a SQL statement with a value of 1.  If only one parallel server was used then parallelism isn't really used at all.  That implies something weird happened - maybe the statement was cancelled before it could allocate more than one thread, or maybe only one thread was available and the statement was downgraded.)

And in the page for [`V$SESSION`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/refrn/V-SESSION.html#GUID-28E2DC75-E157-4C0A-94AB-117C205789B9):

- SID - Session identifier